# Pointing a domain to a specific URL

Tags: redirects, dns, cpanel

Is it possible to point a URL to a specific page in cPanel?

Say I have `foobar.com` and there's a page `foobar.com/art`. Now I also or `artbar.com` and I want to point it at `foobar.com/art` how would I do that?

I'm not seeing an option in cPanel to redirect a domain to a specific URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a *.htaccess* file in the root of `artbar.com`, then simply add the following line:

`redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/newpath`

or if you prefer rewrite method then use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/newpath [R=301]
```

Comment: Ahh ok. Well what if I dont have hosting for artbar.com, i JUST own the domain and I change the nameserver on the domain to point to foobar.com? could I have a .htaccess file in the root of foobar.com that would redirect to the appropriate URL?

Comment: Nope, that won't work - you'd need to configure your name server to understand that referring domain. Name Servers on webhosting accounts unless you have a dedicated one using your own name servers which is unlikely unless you've paid extra then your name servers will be hosting 1,000's if not 100,000's of sites. How would they know to point your domain to such your domain? It might work if you have a dedicated IP and point it at the IP, another method could be to use a domain forwarder, many registrars have those... or the best method would be to use the htaccess after setting it up as an

Comment: addon domain inside your cpanel.