# DNS created and pointed to new IP, but showing a blank page - do I have to redirect it using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns, subdomain, cpanel

How would I go about configuring my web server to handle a domain that's already configured using DNS to then redirect it to a folder?

My friend pointed his domain `forum.example.com` to my forums at: `forums.example.org`. When you visit the first page, it's displaying a blank white page.

Do I have to redirect it using *.htaccess*?

Answer (score 1):

The webserver must be configured correctly so it knows how to respond to a request for a specific URL. If you're running an Apache webserver (the most common one) you can find more information about this in the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

If that is working, you may refer to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/pointing-a-domain-to-a-specific-url?rq=1) in order to redirect all requests to the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

Apache must be configured in order to accepts the requests coming from the hostname `forum.example.com` and consider them an alias for `forums.example.com`.

You can accomplish it by changing the virtual host [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive to include `forum.example.com` as alias of your forum hostname.

Unfortunately, this is not possible unless you have access to the webserver configuration. Thus, if you have a shared hosting, you need to contact your provider to see if they can configure it for you.